# I can't find the user and sum

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

i have a problem, i need to add the debt of a user

controller:

```
 public function cliente($id){

        // $nota = App\Nota::find($id);
    
        //Aquí valida si existe sino redirije al 404
        $datos = [
            'category_name' => 'datatable',
            'page_name' => 'multiple_tables',
        'registro' => Registro::find($id),

        ];

        $cliente = \App\Models\User::findOrFail($id);
    
    
        return view('cliente', compact('cliente'))->with($datos);
    }
```

blade.php

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <h4>Debt Sum:</h4>
</div>
<div class="col">
 {{ $registro->user_id->sum('deuda') }}
</div>
```

Database:

[image]

i need to add the field "deuda" of the user, the relationship is in user_id with the users table

the error that I get is: **Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object**

help pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to calculate sum of the registrations in your controller:

```
 public function cliente($id){

        // $nota = App\Nota::find($id);
    
        //Aquí valida si existe sino redirije al 404
        $datos = [
            'category_name' => 'datatable',
            'page_name' => 'multiple_tables',
            'registro' => Registro::find($id),
        ];

        $cliente = \App\Models\User::findOrFail($id);
    
        $sum = Register::where('user_id', $cliente->id)->sum('deuda');
    
        return view('cliente', compact('cliente','sum'))->with($datos);
    }
```

and in your view use `sum` variable

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <h4>Debt Sum:</h4>
</div>
<div class="col">
 {{ $sum ? $sum : 0 }}
</div>
```